# Acessing array in vega lite

Tags: vega

I need to perform an operation in vega-lite/Kibana 6.5 similar to the next one. I need to  divide y axis by "data.values[0].b". How can I perform this operation?

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "description": "A simple bar chart with embedded data.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": 28}, {"a": "B", "b": 55}, {"a": "C", "b": 43},
      {"a": "D", "b": 91}, {"a": "E", "b": 81}, {"a": "F", "b": 53},
      {"a": "G", "b": 19}, {"a": "H", "b": 87}, {"a": "I", "b": 52}
    ]
  },
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "a", "type": "ordinal"},
    "y": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [Transform Calculate](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/calculate.html) topic in Vega Lite docs.

You can do :

```
"transform": [
    {"calculate": "datum.a / datum.b", "as": "y"}
  ]
```

Notice that 'datum' is the keyword used to access data set.